# How to pick point with out key press in pyvista

Tags: python, pyvista

I am using pyvista to visualize stl file. To get point information, i used below code to achieve this

```
import pyvista as pv

p = pv.Plotter()

mesh = pv.read(filename)

p.add_mesh(mesh) 

def callback(x, y) :return

p.enable_point_picking(callback=callback) 

p.show()
```

I could pick point by keeping cursor on point and press key 'P'.

I want this function without key press by clicking on mouse. is it possible?

Comment: it uses `mouse click` with `mouse move` to rotate object - and ir could be big problem to rewrite module to detect that you use `click` only to select point.

Comment: If not with keypress, how would you want to be able to pick a point? What would you want to happen with picking? Same as now, storing the data? Or are you more looking for an interactive data cursor kind of solution? (Either way I don't think pyvista has anything for this.)

Comment: Hi. I want same function. If left click gives issue. Right click also fine. I tried with pyautogui to call function. It was work fine. But happening only on first click. Refer below code for more clarity.               def callback(x):pyautogui.Keypress('k')       
    Plotter.track_click_position(callback=callback, side='right')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got one solution for this action. as pyvista is base from vtk, i used vtk function and it is working fine. if anyone found better solution, please post.

```
mouse=pv._vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
mouse.SetDefaultRenderer(plotter.ren_win.GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer())
plotter.SetInteractorStyle(mouse)

def clicked(m,event):
    try:
        modifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
        if modifiers==QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:pass
        else:
            clickPos = m.GetInteractor().GetEventPosition()
            picker = pv._vtk.vtkPointPicker()
            picker.Pick(clickPos[0], clickPos[1],0, m.GetDefaultRenderer())
            actor=picker.GetActor()
            if actor!=None:print(actor)
            m.OnLeftButtonDown()
    except Exception as e:print(e)
mouse.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", clicked)
```

Thanks [biomode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759349/how-to-pick-point-with-out-key-press-in-pyvista/69823037#:%7E:text=at%2010%3A10-,biomode,-26). i edited my code as per your suggestion. it looks better

```
def clicked(event):
    picker = pv._vtk.vtkPropPicker()
    picker.PickProp(event[0], event[1],plotter.ren_win.GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer())
    actor=picker.GetActor()
    if actor!=None:print(actor)
plotter.track_click_position(callback=clicked,side='left', viewport=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `track_click_position` method of pyvista Plotter and still use your callback function as above. The documentation is [here](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.track_click_position.html?highlight=track).